# elasticsearch autocomplete for some field values

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm storing articles in elasticsearch such as this in an articles index:

```json
{
  "title": "my title",
  "text": "article text",
  "date": "2023-11-28T00:00:00Z",
  "authors": ["author 1", "author 2"],
  "section": "article section"
}
```

With the following mapping:

```json
{
  "title": { type: "text" },
  "text": { type: "text" },
  "date": { type: "date" },
  "authors": { type: "keyword" },
  "section": { type: "keyword" }
```

Now in the search UI of my application, I want to give the user a way to search the authors that are stored in all the documents so he can filter on them. The same with section.

Is there a way to query just the discrete values in the field on the articles index or do I need to have a separate index for the authors and sections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the [Terms enum API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-terms-enum.html) that make it easy to do a prefix search on the values.

```
GET /articles/_terms_enum
{
    "field" : "authors",
    "string" : "searchterm"
}
```

Although [@val](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77562885/1353412) suggestion can be used with any query, I think this is a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`terms` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) to do just that:

```
POST index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "authors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "authors",
        "size": 10
      }
    },
    "sections": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "section",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Another way is to use the [suggesters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/8.11/search-suggesters.html), such as the term or completion suggesters.